# Getting and logging current *weather conditions* in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible in ROS to record current weather conditions from a website or weather-indicator in Ubuntu?
I would like to record current atmosphere temperature, humidity, etc for some experiments.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192085/getting-and-logging-current-*weather-conditions*-in-ros/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-06**:
google "waether api with c++ wrapper" , your question is not ROS specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of a ROS node which does this already.

It shouldn't be too hard to writea node like this in python if you can find a python library which can query the current weather information.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1